# Can't launch Minecraft 1.12.2 and under

Tags: java, openjdk, minecraft

I cannot launch Minecraft version 1.12.2 and under.

I read forums saying to use Java 8, and that still doesn't work.

Following commands were executed followed by a computer restart:

```
name@name-ThinkPad-Edge-E430c:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
[sudo] password for name: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-8-jre is already the newest version (8u252-b09-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 128 not upgraded.
name@name-ThinkPad-Edge-E430c:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
name@name-ThinkPad-Edge-E430c:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1ubuntu1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, you chose difficult way.

There is specially prepared [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/minecraft) by Martin Wimpress with both client and server for Minecraft:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/minecraft
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
# sudo apt-get install minecraft-server-installer # for server
```

Comment: Appreciate the attempt to help but this would not work for other custom Minecraft launchers.

Comment: I have just tried, the installer works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Do not know much details about the game.